# Sphinx 1.2.3 integration with rst2pdf

Tags: python, pdf, python-sphinx

I have Python and Sphinx installed on my windows machine. I have followed this tutorial from [here](http://thyagjs.blogspot.com/2012/05/create-pdf-document-from-your-sphinx.html) and few things were not clear to me:

The text below is a reference from the tutorial that did not make sense to me and am guessing its the reason why I cannot have PDF files created.

> Again in the conf.py file, add the below content at the end. Change the pdf_documents parameter according your project (index filename, pdf file name, document title on first page, and the author name)

Basically I downloaded the rst2pdf library from github and extracted it on my downloads folder and from there executed:

```
C:\Users\Luyando.Siko\Downloads\rst2pdf-master\rst2pdf-master>python setup.py install
```

I was confronted with many issues which am not sure whether to be worried about or not. Is this the correct way to have rst2pdf installed to my sphinx to begin with? Can someone please explain to me what the writer meant on the blockquote text.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Again in the conf.py file, add the below content at the end. Change the pdf_documents parameter according your project (index filename, pdf file name, document title on first page, and the author name)

Basically, what this means is that you copy the large block of PDF Options (starting with:
`# -- Options for PDF output --------- etc.`
) into the bottom of your `conf.py` file.

Then, you can modify these configuration settings to suit your project. So using their example:

```
pdf_documents = [
('index', u'EMSDocumentation', u'EMS Documentation', u'Thyag Sundaramoorthy'),
]
```

You start with `index.rst` and then convert that into `EMSDocumentation.pdf`, entitled `EMS Documentation`, with author, `Thyag Sundaramoorthy`.